# Need to return string in SQL Query using FOR XML PATH when Values in Select string are Null

Tags: sql-server

Our application gets option values for select2 dropdownlist from the database using For XML Path to concatenante strings.  It works fine as long as there are values in the table, but if there aren't any values, it returns NULL.  I have tried wrapping the entire this in COAELESCE like this:

```
SELECT 
STUFF(
(
SELECT COALESCE('<option value=""></option><option value="0">Add New</option><option value='''+ cast(dm.DataMapId as varchar(30)) +''' >'+replace(isnull(dm.Name,''),'`','''')  +'</option>','<option value=""></option><option value="0">Add New</option>')
From tbl_DataMap dm
WHERE Active = 1

order by dm.Name Asc
  FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 0, '')
```

I tried using IsNull on the "Name" field:

```
SELECT 
STUFF(
(
SELECT '<option value=""></option><option value="0">Add New</option><option value='''+ cast(dm.DataMapId as varchar(30)) +''' >'+replace(isnull(dm.Name,'<option value=""></option><option value="0">Add New</option>'),'`','''')  +'</option>'
From tbl_DataMap dm
WHERE Active = 1

order by dm.Name Asc
  FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 0, '')
```

I want to return the string "`<option value=""></option><option value="0">Add New</option>`" if there are no records returned.

This is what I get when there are records:

[image]

Comment: Wrap the subquery with `ISNULL`/`COALESCE`.

Comment: Also, what is the point of the `STUFF` here? It doesn't do anything. You replace `0` characters at the start of the string with `''`. It does literally nothing.

Comment: @Lamu - I did not write the query, I am only trying to edit it to return the string that I need.  And as far as I can tell, STUFF, stuffs all the values into one field.

Comment: L A R N U... *"And as far as I can tell, STUFF, stuffs all the values into one field."* What does that even mean? Have a read of [STUFF (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15); all it does it remove characters from one string and inserts another string into it; *"The STUFF function inserts a string into another string. It deletes a specified length of characters in the first string at the start position and then inserts the second string into the first string at the start position."*

Comment: LARNU I don't know how else to explain "stuffs all values into one field"  There could be 10 pairs of Id/Name.  When there are values, they all get stuffed in one field.  Perhaps the picture above may help you to understand my nomenclature

Comment: As I mention, in your string, you are removing `0` characters from position `1` (the start of the string), which is **no** characters, and then you are inserting the string `''` (which is also an empty string) at position 1. Effectively you are therefore prefixing your string with `''`; which is literally pointless.

Comment: The image doesn't demonstrate anything, @Rani. `STUFF({SomeString},1,0,'')` is the same as `SomeString`; end of story.

Comment: As I said, I did not write this, and have not been able to find anything that explains the For xml path parameters.  So are the parementers the problem?

Comment: As I said, at the start of the comments; wrap the subquery in `ISNULL`/`COALESCE`. (and remove the `STUFF`.)

Comment: I tried to use Coalesce above.  ARe you saying put that back in like it was and remove stuff?

Comment: `COALESCE` is **inside** your subquery, not outside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, just use `COALESCE` or `ISNULL`:

```sql
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT '<option value=""></option><option value="0">Add New</option><option value=''' + CAST(dm.DataMapId AS varchar(30)) + ''' >' + REPLACE(ISNULL(dm.Name, '<option value=""></option><option value="0">Add New</option>'), '`', '''') + '</option>'
               FROM tbl_DataMap dm
               WHERE Active = 1
               ORDER BY dm.Name ASC
               FOR XML PATH('')),'<option value=""></option><option value="0">Add New</option>');
```